# Visual Studio 2022 / Angular standalone - Preserve browser context

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, visual-studio-2022

Unlike an Angular .NET Core project, stand-alone Angular projects do not preserve the browser context between two debugging sessions. Is there a way to force Visual Studio to launch the browser in non-private browsing ?

I'm working on a front application that uses a browser extension. Private Browsing forces me to install/configure the extension every time I launch a new debugging session.

Comment: This has been logged with Microsoft (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/angular-standalone-project-esproj-browser-settings/1635820) please vote up the issue and they may resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this configuration to file *.vscode/launch.json*:

```
{
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "localhost (Chrome)",
    "url": "http://localhost:4200",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "runtimeArgs": [ "--user-data-dir=${workspaceFolder}\\.browserDir\\Chrome" ]
}
```

And create the *.browserDir\Chrome* folder in the solution directory.